# Eclipse AVRDude Error - Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: eclipse, osx-yosemite, avr, atmega, avrdude

i'm using Eclipse Indogo on Mac OS 10.10 and i'm tryig to program an avr atmega 16.
While setting up eclipse I installed all dependencies like Elcipse CDT, avr-elcipse plugin and the CrossPack AVR Development Tools.
But when I try to add a nex Programmer configuration in Eclipse->Preferences->AVRDude I get this Error:
AVRDude executable can not be found.
Cannnot run AVRDude executable.

Why is this? Seems like there is a problem running AVRDude on Yosemite?

Comment: Have you installed [The-AVR-GCC-Toolchain](http://avr-eclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/The_AVR_GCC_Toolchain) ? This could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path that the Eclipse IDE uses to execute avrdude. Click on the "Paths" tab right below "AVRDude", click on the avrdude path, edit, then choose custom.

Mine was in "/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin" and that worked for me.